# Student of many disciplines without the negative connotation of "Dilettante"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for a person who studies many subjects? Often, the words we use to describe this type of person implies that he/she knows little about each subject (e.g. jack-of-all-trades, dilettante). I'd like to avoid that negative meaning.

e.g. Steve was a true ________; he was well-versed in everything from theoretical physics to gastronomy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath):

> A ***polymath*** is a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas.

You could also use ***Renaissance Man*** to hearken back to the time when being a generalist didn't make you a "*"jack of all trades,  master of none"*. Notice that Wikipedia redirects "Renaissance Man" to "Polymath".

Comment: And of course ***polyhistor*** in parallel to _polymath_.

Comment: Note also that these terms have been given in duplicate threads.

Answer (score 0):

How about *genius*?

M-W:

> *genius*: a very smart or talented person : a person who has a
>   level of talent or intelligence that is very rare or remarkable

Your example:

> Steve was a true *genius*; he was well-versed in everything from
>   theoretical physics to gastronomy.

Comment: No, one can be a genius, yet limited to a single narrow field, e.g. Paul Erdős.  Or one can be just reasonably intelligent, but educated in many fields.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but genius often is much broader. Erdos was exceptionally narrow. Consider Einstein instead. There are many others like him. For example, I  wouldn't call Leibnitz  a polymath. While he was a polymath, I'd still call him a a genius. Most people familiar with him would do the same.