# What would you call someone interested in many things?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who is interested in many things? (Not dilettante)

Comment: Could you use Renaissance to describe the person? Dilettante, a slur, says dabbling, whereas Renaissance says accomplished.

Comment: What kind of things?

Comment: I voted to close due to lack of research could also have marked as a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358065/student-of-many-disciplines-without-the-negative-connotation-of-dilettante  or many others

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about the word you want. Please refer to the checklist in the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 3):

**polymath** "a person of wide-ranging knowledge or learning."

or, from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath), " a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas"

Comment: Hmmm...expertise does not equate with interest necessarily, does it?

Comment: @thomj1332 - Well, it's hard to become expert without interest.

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind first is ***renaissance man***:

> ***[Renaissance man](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/renaissance_man)***
>   (also Renaissance woman)
>
> NOUN
>
> A person with many talents or areas of knowledge.

But there's also ***polymath*** which is pretty much spot on:

> ***[Polymath](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polymath)***
>
> NOUN
>
> A person of wide knowledge or learning.
>   *‘a Renaissance polymath’*

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the the term 'Da Vinci' used to describe someone who has a wide range of interests and is astute in his pursuit of these - "John is somewhat of a Da Vinci, he loves science, art and mechanics."

Answer (score -2):

***Worldling*** according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worldling) means:

> a person engrossed in the concerns of this present world

Comment: "Worldling" has the negative connotation that the person concerns himself with worldly, mundane things. It does not say that the person has a wide range interests.