# Is there a succinct term for "adequate at many things, good at a handful"?

Tags: phrase-requests

The phrase "jack of all trades, master of none" would refer to someone who is consistently adequate. The term "polymath" implies someone who has reached a high level in many areas of knowledge or skill.

What about someone who is indeed a master of some?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would you call someone interested in many things?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391013/what-would-you-call-someone-interested-in-many-things) See: *Renaissance man/woman*

Comment: Why would there be a word for this? This is just a normal person.

Comment: This question would be helped by specifying why *master* or *specialist* don't fit. It's hard for me to see much daylight between *master* (of one?) and *master* (of two or more things but not many things).